# How to access a single ArrayList in ArrayListMultiMap

Tags: java

I would like to get an entry from ArrayList in an ArrayListMultiMap. I am using Google Guava ArrayListMultimap and each key is associated with multiple array lists. For example, for the key1 I have 4 array lists, and each ArrayList contains 2 entries. I need to be able to access a particular ArrayList and get an entry from there so my question is how do I do it? Every time I try to access the value associated with the key it prints all 4 array lists but I need only one.

```
Multimap<String, ArrayList<String>> wordAsKey = ArrayListMultimap.create();

for (DictionaryEntries dict : DictionaryEntries.values()) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String key = dict.getKey();
        String partOfSpeech = dict.getPartOfSpeech();
        String definition = dict.getDefinition();
        list.add(partOfSpeech);
        list.add(definition);
        wordAsKey.put(key, list);
    }

ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
resultList.add(wordAsKey.get(word).toString());
System.out.println(resultList);
```

Prints

[[[noun, A set of pages.], [noun, A written work published in printed or electronic form.], [verb, To arrange for someone to have a seat on a plane.], [verb, To arrange something on a particular date.]]]

But I need it to print only [noun, A set of pages.]

Answer (score 0):

you can try: get index value

```
int index = 0;
resultList.add(wordAsKey.get(word).get(index).toString());
```

Comment: I cannot use .get(index) method after .get(word) because the IDE just does not allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this -

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)wordAsKey.get(word);
String result = list.get(index);
System.out.println(result);
```

And you can check whether particular String is exist or not in List, then see below;

```
if(list.contains("search")){...}
```